# b=p Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in NameError: name 'p' is not defined

Tags: python

Este codigo es para hacer el metodo de la biseccion pero no logro hacer que funcione, muchas gracias de antemano:

```
from math import*
def f(x):
    return 10*x**4-3*x*exp(x)-3*exp(x)
def biseccion(f,a,b,tol,n):
    i=1
    while i<=n:
        p=a+(b-a)/2.0
        print("Iter=","%03d" % i," ; p=","%.14f" % p)
        if abs(f(p))<= 1e-15 or (b-a)/2.0 < tol:
            return p
        i+=1
        if f(a)*f(p) > 0:
            a=p
        else:
            b=p
    print("Iteraciones agotadas:Error")
    return
print("Método de la bisección:")
biseccion(f,-1.0,-0.25,1e-4,100)
```

me sale esto:

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > b=p
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > NameError: name 'p' is not defined

Comment: solo debes definir `p=0` antes del while con esto ya python no evaluara la `p` y no marcara error

Comment: Probé tu código y funciona sin error. La variable `p` se define tan pronto entras al `while` en función de los parámetros recibidos. ¿Estas seguro de publicar el código correcto?

Comment: Si en teoria no debería haber ningún error pero me arroja eso y siempre es por los identados

Comment: Utilizo visual Studio

Comment: solo elimine totalmente visual studio y lo volvi a instalar y ya funciona